# EntityFramework Many to Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Since upgrading to EF 6.1.3 I am unable to save anything to the DB.

I get an error:

> "Unable to update the EntitySet 'ProjectTask' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation."

The Tables define a many to many relationship:

### Project

- Id INT PK

### ProjectTask

- ProjectId INT
- TaskId INT

### Task

- Id INT PK

with all foreign keys defined. Pretty standard.

Some posts indicated that the joining table `ProjectTask` must have a primary key defined.  But, if I do that EF creates the `ProjectTask` class in the data model which is not good.

Comment: Your `ProjectTask` table does not have a primary key. Make `ProjectId` and `TaskId` the composite primary key for that table.

Comment: `ProjectTask` needs to have a PK that is a compound key of the `ProjectId` and `TaskId`, not it's own `Id` field.....

Comment: @Claies This is not really necessary if third table is being generated by code first migration then EF Migration would create third table with composite key defined.

Comment: This is database first but I thought EF would be able to infer row uniqueness as ProjectTask uses foreign key constraints to reference primary keys for both columns; however, it seems EF isn't that smart. I added a composite PK to ProjectTask (which is unfortunate as it's superfluous and likely to reduce performance) but EF does now work.  It seems like a poor solution to me and I'll keep looking for something better!

Comment: You *can* modify the models generated by Database First and remove the `DefiningQuery`, and Entity Framework will be able to use the join table even without the PK.  However, without the composite PK, it may be possible to get the join table into an inconsistent state, and cause EF to crash at runtime.  The chance is low, and would require manual table modification, but it is there.  Also, modifying the model has the potential to be undone if the model is re-scaffolded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a few people mentioned.  Creating a composite key on ProjectTask table was the solution.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ProjectTask
    ADD CONSTRAINT ProjectTask_ProjectId_TaskId UNIQUE (ProjectId, TaskId)
```